# Como puedo obtener el Path de un archivo creado en una carpeta especifica? Android Xamarin

Tags: android, archivo, xamarin, rutas, fileupload

Estoy creando una carpeta donde se guardarán archivos en formato json, para después seleccionar ese archivo (y todos los que se encuentren en esa carpeta) para subirlos a la nube de mega.

Si crea la carpeta, si se crea el archivo json pero al momento de querer subirlo a la nube de mega el path del archivo me dice que no existe.

Alguien me puede apoyar???

En la nube de mega también se crean las carpetas necesarias, si hay conexión y si hace las carpetas, pero no sube el archivo.

El código donde tengo el problema es el siguiente:

```
   try
             {//Ubicacion del archivo
                var carpeta = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes + nombreUsuario +_+ReportNumber+.json");

                // Subimos el archivo al directorio , pasando la ruta del archivo a subir y el directorio de mega donde debe subirlo.
                INode subir = Client.UploadFile(carpeta, DBDirectory);

                /*                                       
                    ubicacion del archivo a subir en el celular
                    /storage/emulated/0/Nube_JG/Reportes/Hola/Hola_0.json
                */

            }
            catch (Exception error)
             {
                // Algo ha fallado, abortamos el subproceso.
                // Mensaje en pantalla para informar al usuario del error.
                await DisplayAlert("MAL: ", "ALGO MALO A PASADO, REVISAR CODIGO, Error al subir el archivo", "OK");

             }
```

Muestro el codigo que tengo completo:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Memcached;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using CG.Web.MegaApiClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoFixture.Kernel;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.TizenSpecific;

using System.IO;

namespace PruebaNube
{
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        string nombreUsuario = nombreEntry.Text;
        // ubicacion para carpetas contenedoras de reportes
        var ReportFolder =   System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes/" + nombreUsuario);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(ReportFolder)) ;
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ReportFolder);
           await  DisplayAlert("Creado", "Se a creado la carpeta en el directorio", "OK");
        }

        int a = 1;
        int ReportNumber = 0;
        var NewReport = System.IO.Path.Combine(ReportFolder + "/" + nombreUsuario + "_" + ReportNumber + ".json");

        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter ReportWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(System.IO.Path.Combine(NewReport)))
        {
            using (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter ReportJsonWriter = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(ReportWriter))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(ReportJsonWriter, nombreUsuario+" a donde el mundo nos lleve" );
            }
        }
        await DisplayAlert("Creado", "el archivo correspondiente json fue creado", "OK");

    }

    private async void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        string nombreUsuario = nombreEntry.Text;

        try
        {
            MegaApiClient Client = new MegaApiClient();
            Client.Login("*****@gmail.com", "*******"); //(cuenta,contraseña)
            await DisplayAlert("Hola: ", "INICIADA LA SESION", "OK");
            var nodes = Client.GetNodes();   // Obtenemos los nodos (directorios/archivos) de la cuenta dentro de una variable.           

            bool DBAvaible = Client.GetNodes().Any(n => n.Name == nombreUsuario);     // Comprobar si existe algún nodo (directorio).

            INode root;
            //INode root = nodes.Single(x => x.Type == NodeType.Root); //Obtenemos el nodo raíz.
            INode DBDirectory;

            if (DBAvaible == true)
                 {
                    // Como la carpeta ya existe, no se creara una nueva, se trabajara sobre la misma
                    await DisplayAlert("Achis Achis los Mariachis ", "La carpeta en Mega ya existe", "Enterado");
                    DBDirectory = nodes.Single(n => n.Name == nombreUsuario);

            }
            else
                 {
                    root = nodes.Single(n => n.Type == NodeType.Root);
                    // Como la carpeta no existe en la Nube, se implementara a crear la carpeta
                    DBDirectory = Client.CreateFolder(nombreUsuario, root);       // Creamos el directorio en la raíz.

                     await DisplayAlert("Vaya vaya la Papaya ", "Al parecer se creeo la carpeta en Mega", "OK");

            }

             try
             {//Ubicacion del archivo
                var carpeta = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes + nombreUsuario +_+ReportNumber+.json");

                // Subimos el archivo al directorio , pasando la ruta del archivo a subir y el directorio de mega donde debe subirlo.
                INode subir = Client.UploadFile(carpeta, DBDirectory);

                /*                                       
                    ubicacion del archivo a subir en el celular
                    /storage/emulated/0/Nube_JG/Reportes/Hola/Hola_0.json
                */

            }
            catch (Exception error)
             {
                // Algo ha fallado, abortamos el subproceso.
                // Mensaje en pantalla para informar al usuario del error.
                await DisplayAlert("MAL: ", "ALGO MALO A PASADO, REVISAR CODIGO, Error al subir el archivo", "OK");

             }


            Client.Logout();

            await DisplayAlert("Listo: ", "Cerrar Sesión", "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            // Algo ha fallado, abortamos el subproceso.

           await DisplayAlert("ERROR DE CONEXION: ", "Revisar conexion a internet, y vuelva a intentarlo", "OK");
            // MessageBox.Show("Errorntentar subir el archivo. " + error.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);




        }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que aqui esta tu error. ya que le quieres pasar una variable concatenada y esta todo dentro de las comillas, lo cual no concatenas nada.

```
 var carpeta = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes + nombreUsuario +_+ReportNumber+.json");
```

Asi deberia quedar.

```
 var carpeta = System.IO.Path.Combine(global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/Nube_JG/Reportes/" + nombreUsuario +"_"+ReportNumber+".json");
```

Comment: Así fue, gracias, el Path ya funciona, lo comprobé editando el archivo json anteriormente creado, sin embargo aun tengo el problema de subir el archivo a mega, buscare información, Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ok, marca la respuesta como correcta.